# ggplot2 stacked bar graph in which every value is a group/color

Tags: r, ggplot2

this is my first post and I am new to coding, I apologise if my post is not clean or I havent looked for answers enough.

I am trying to plot a stacked bar graph with ggplot2 and am almost there. Here is what I have so far. I have a data set with 2 columns (Length and Count). I have attached it to this post. I read it and plot it like this:

```
example <- read.delim("example.txt", sep",")
ggplot(data=example, aes(x=Length, y=Count, fill=Count))+geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

The graph this gives me is Fig1A

What I am looking for, however, is that every value in the column "Count" is given its own color. It should look like Fig1B (Excel example):

I tried to plot it the way I would plot it in Excel (Fig1C) but was not able to replicate this kind of plot with ggplot2, I wasnt able to have my data.frame fit this kind of layout.

[image: Fig1A-C]
[Example file (example.txt](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=20049229006115736377)

Thank you

Comment: Welcome! [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) is a post to help you post reproducible examples.

Comment: Don't post links to data. Links break.

Comment: Thank you! I will make sure to keep that in mind for my next post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the column count as a factor, rather than the column itsself.

```
ggplot(data=example, aes(x=Length, y=Count, fill=factor(Count)))+geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

returns [image: colorbar]

ggplot automatically chooses a gradient color scale, but you can change it with a different color palette or a manual list of colors for each factor. For example, you can choose a random color for each level in your dataset by calling:

```
colors <- sample(colours(),length(levels(factor(example$Count))))
```

and adding this to your plot

```
+ scale_fill_manual(values = colors)
```

which gives something similar to this:
[image: randcolor]

alternatively, you can choose to follow R's built in color codes. Try running

```
colours()
```

and you will get a full list of available colors. You can hand pick as many as you need or you can select the first n elements, with n equal to your amount of levels

```
colors <- colours()[seq(1,length(levels(factor(example$Count))),by=1)]
```

and following the above procedure. That consistently gives this graph:

[image: fixed]

Comment: Thank you! That was what I was looking for.

Comment: No problem, you can use the tick mark next to the answer to accept it as solved. Welcome to the site!

Comment: Yes of course! If I may add a question: Now I am trying to have a colorscheme similar to the second image you have posted, I used your code which assigns random colors. However, this means that every new data file looks different, I would like to have a consistent colorscheme. How can I set a specific color scheme that adds as many colors as I have values?

Comment: I have edited my answer to include what you were asking